# Is it possible to transfer minting authority of a Solana Token to another account using CLI?

Tags: solana, nft, solana-cli

I created a fungible token on mainnet using a file system wallet, which I understand is not secure if I were wanting to do anything substantial. I also have my rent-exempt amount of SOL tied up in that file system wallet (not much, but not nothing either).

I'm wondering if I can transfer the minting authority to my Ledger, making it more secure, without having to lose my first token? My understanding is the minting authority account is the one that needs to hold the SOL in order to make it rent exempt. Transferring the SOL is easy, but wasn't sure about the authority, such that I could have everything under one hardware wallet going forward.

Hopefully my question makes sense, but absolutely willing to clarify anything!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can run:

```
$ spl-token authorize <YOUR_TOKEN_PUBKEY> mint <YOUR_LEDGER_PUBKEY>
```

More info and examples at https://spl.solana.com/token#command-line-utility